# How to search nsmutablearray in objective c-iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am reading a RSS feed into nsmutablearray. i want to search the xml feed. for that i want to search nsmutablearray. i am very new to iphone apps. can some one helpme with this..

thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do "searching" of arrays using predicates, like so:

```
NSMutableArray* names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Andy", @"Bart", @"Bob", nil]; 
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'b'"];
NSArray* namesStartingWithB = [names filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
// namesStartingWithB now contains @"Bart" & @"Bob"
```

You should look at the [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) and [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/) documentation for more information. If you're after information specific to parsing XML (i.e. an RSS feed), you should check out Matt Gallagher's article on [using libxml2 for XML parsing and XPath queries in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html).

Comment: shouldnt 

NSArray* namesStartingWithB = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];

be 

NSArray* namesStartingWithB = [names filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];

Comment: @James Thanks for the heads up -- fixed.