# What does setFetchBatchSize do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

If i set this, my request returns a higher number of results that I requested, but most of them are faulted. What would happen if i tried to access a faulted one? Would it make another one faulted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319188/setfetchbatchsize-doesnt-seem-to-work-properly It may help you

Comment: This will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319188/setfetchbatchsize-doesnt-seem-to-work-properly

Answer (score 1):

The setFetchBatchSize method sets the ammount of objects to fetch at a time. Anyway, you have to check the "isFault" property of each NSManagedObject. "Faulted" item it is just unused item at this point of time / request.